# VEEAM cmdlets not working with powershell variables

Tags: veeam

Storing the server name in variable from the VEEAM commandlets is not working as the value coming in variable is some other property of the server.

While storing VEEAM `Get-VBRServer` to a variable in PowerShell, the value coming to variable is some other property of the server.

How the server name can be retrieved and stored from the cmdlets?